# JPA Hibernate OneToMany Enum - Unmapped Class Error

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, enums

I'm trying to store a Set of an Enum in my Entity-class with JPA/Hibernate, but I keep getting an error concerning "an unmapped class" while I actually have an Enum. What am I doing wrong?

Error I'm getting: (formatted into multiple lines for readability)

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource 
 [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: 

Invocation of init method failed; 
nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: 
Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: path.to.my.MyEnum
```

Declaration

```
@Entity(name=MyEntity)
@Table(name=myentity)
public class MyEntity {

    ....

    @ElementCollection
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Set<MyEnum> something;

    ....
}
```

My Enum:

```
public enum MyEnum {

    ONE("one string"),
    TWO("two string"),
    THREE("three string");

    private final String name;

    private MyEnum(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only use `@OneToMany` annotations for classes annotated with `@Entity`. Remove the annotation and it should work.

Comment: That helped! I can now also "save" an object from my application, when I try to get it from storage I get another error:  org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role   ....MyClass.something , could not initialize proxy - no Session;  Any idea if this is related?

Comment: changing  @ElementCollection (fetch = FetchType.EAGER)  fixed it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Cribber If you want more control over the name of the table and its columns JPA/Hibernate creates to save your elementcollection you can use the `@CollectionTable` and `@Column` annotations to do so.